# How to find if the values in two columns appear in reverse in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am pretty new to this, but I'm trying to find if the values in column a and column b appear in reverse order or (another way to say it) where the values are swapped, anywhere else in the columns - if so write 1 in column c, if not write 0 in column c.

Expected output:

```
column_a  column_b  column_c

1. a      b        1
2. b      a        1
3. d      a        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `np.sort` then pass the result to `duplicated`

```
df['New']=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['column_a','column_b']])).duplicated(keep=False).astype(int)
df
Out[1292]: 
  column_a column_b  column_c  New
0        a        b         1    1
1        b        a         1    1
2        d        a         0    0
```

Comment: I see what you did there - I definitely did not think of it that way. This worked - thanks so much.

Comment: @max yw~ happy coding